# Magento transfer html price value to cart

Tags: php, jquery, magento

I was successfully able to change the value of the "price" class on [this page](http://www.flyingcakes.in/eshop/index.php/fresh-fruits-cake.html) using this jQuery script:

```
jQuery("#options_46_2").click(function(){
                var priceOldValue = parseInt(jQuery('.product-options-bottom .price-box .price').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));
                if (this.checked) {
                    var selectedWeight = jQuery("#select_32 option:selected").text();
                    selectedWeight = parseFloat(selectedWeight);
                    var priceNewValue = priceOldValue + 50 * selectedWeight;
                    jQuery(".product-options-bottom .price-box .price").html("Rs" + priceNewValue + ".00");

                }
                else {
                    jQuery(".product-options-bottom .price-box .price").html("Rs" + priceOldValue + ".00");
                }

        });
```

Now, I want this changed value to be the actual value of the product's price when a user clicks on "Add to cart" button. How should I do it?

Also, is there any more elegant way to do this, for other products?

Comment: can you add custom product option for Do you want your cake to be Egg-less? and set it price it will automatically add price if this is selected

Comment: Thanks keyur for replying. The problem is that I want the price to be calculated by weight, which can easily be done by using "custom product option" drop-down, but if a customer wants an egg-less cake, the price should be added ON TOP of the price which is calculated by the drop-down. Like this:
The base price of cake is Rs.540, if a user selects 2KG from the drop-down Rs. 520 is added to the price, so now price becomes 540+520 = 1040. Now if user clicks on egg-less 'yes' option, the price should then add Rs. 50 more for every KG to the total.
i.e. 1040+(2*50) = 1140.

Comment: This cannot be achieved by using custom product option.

Comment: have you find solution?

Comment: nope. Still trying to do it, preferably without creating an extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

then you can achieve this using **observer** create one module and add event  `sales_quote_add_item`  this event fire after product add to cart

and in your observer you can get product price and check option is selected or not if 
option is selected then you can set quote price using

`$quote_item->setOriginalCustomPrice($Custom price)`

Comment: Sir, need to add Rs. 50 for every kilo. For example, if a customer selects 1 KG then Rs. 50 should be added if they slect egg-less 'yes' option.
If a customer selects 1.5KG, Rs. 75 should be added.
If a customer selects 2KG, Rs. 100 should be added.
[Check this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/F3asP7m.png)

Comment: I noticed [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) that the 'observer' is broken for the recent versions of magento. Bummer! There has to be some other way. Meanwhile can you please vote up the question so that it gets more attention.

Comment: For some reason the magento wiki link is not working, here's the direct link: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Comment: what? please visit this http://www.meteorify.com/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/ for creating module

Comment: Keyur, thanks! After trying out different things, I found out that observer is the only way to do this.

Comment: its my pleasure to help you